# I have a program that's "bruteforcing" an equation in Python, is there a way of making it a lot faster?

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, math

The code is the one below, to get anything over 5 answers it is taking a very long time, is there a way to make this code faster? Thanks in advance.

```
    for a in range (2, 500):
        for b in range(2,1500):
            if (0.5*k-1)*a * (a+1) * (2*a+1)/6 + (-0.5*k+2)*a*(a+1)/2== (0.5*k-1)*b**2+(-0.5*k+2):
                print(k, str(a), str(b), int((0.5*k-1)*b**2+(-0.5*k+2)*b))
```

Comment: For example https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html

Answer (score 1):

Well, the *first* thing that comes to mind is stripping out the common sub-expressions.

Since the *entire* left side of the equality comparison uses `a` but not `b` (`k` can be ignored, it appears to be a constant here, if not for the entire program, then at least for the duration of this code segment), you can calculate it *once,* before the `b` loop starts. In other words, something like:

```
for a in range (2, 500):
    lhs = (0.5*k-1)*a*(a+1)*(2*a+1)/6 + (-0.5*k+2)*a*(a+1)/2
    for b in range(2,1500):
        if lhs == (0.5*k-1)*b**2+(-0.5*k+2):
            print(k, str(a), str(b), int((0.5*k-1)*b**2+(-0.5*k+2)*b))
```

But a possibly even *faster* way of doing it is realising that the `a/b` mapping seems to be a one-to-one relationship<sup>(a)</sup>. So, rather than checking every single possible `b`, *calculate* the desired `b` from `a` and confirm that it is both:

- an integer; and
- in the range `2..1499` inclusive.

That should speed up things by about a factor of `1500`.

The formula to get `b` would be discovered with something like:

```
   (0.5*k-1)*b**2+(-0.5*k+2) = (0.5*k-1)*a*(a+1)*(2*a+1)/6+(-0.5*k+2)*a*(a+1)/2

=> (0.5*k-1)*b**2 = (0.5*k-1)*a*(a+1)*(2*a+1)/6+(-0.5*k+2)*a*(a+1)/2-(-0.5*k+2)
   (subtract (-0.5*k+2) from both sides)

=> b**2 = ((0.5*k-1)*a*(a+1)*(2*a+1)/6+(-0.5*k+2)*a*(a+1)/2-(-0.5*k+2))/(0.5*k-1)
    [divide both sides by (0.5*k-1)]

=> b = sqrt(((0.5*k-1)*a*(a+1)*(2*a+1)/6+(-0.5*k+2)*a*(a+1)/2-(-0.5*k+2))/(0.5*k-1))
    [take square root of both sides]
```

Now I *think* that's correct but you should probably/definitely check it - I suffer enough helping my teenage son with *his* math so, while the steps may be wrong, the approach is sound. The general idea is to start with the equality you have in your code and do the same thing to both sides until you get something along the lines of `b = some_fn_of(a)`.

Then it becomes the far more succinct:

```
for a in range (2, 500):
    b = some_fn_of(a)
    if b == int(b) and b >= 2 and b < 1500:
        print(k, str(a), str(b), int((0.5*k-1)*b**2+(-0.5*k+2)*b))
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> *Technically,* the presence of `b**2` makes it a two-to-one mapping since the square root of a non-negative number can be the positive or negative value. That doesn't seem to matter here since the range of possible `b` values are all positive.